# flutter marker not showing on map

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am using google maps. I want to create a marker but it's not showing on the map.

My code

```
                     ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: address['Address'].length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return SideInAnimation(
                            index,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              // onTap: widget.onPressed,
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  dateindex = index;
                                  addressSelected =
                                      address['Address'][index];
                                  print(addressSelected);
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: dateindex == index
                                        ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                        : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                    width: dateindex == index ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                        showAddress
                                            ? address['Address'][index]
                                                ['Address']
                                            : '...',
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .headline4),
                                    SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                    Container(
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                              .size
                                              .height *
                                          0.2,
                                      child: GoogleMap(
                                        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController
                                            controller) {
                                          _controller.complete(controller);
                                          setState(() {
                                            _markers.add(Marker(
                                                markerId: MarkerId('1'),
                                                position: LatLng(
                                                    double.parse(
                                                        address['Address']
                                                                [index]
                                                            ['Latitude']),
                                                    double.parse(address[
                                                                'Address']
                                                            [index]
                                                        ['Longitude']))));
                                          });
                                        },
                                        initialCameraPosition:
                                            CameraPosition(
                                                target: LatLng(
                                                    double.parse(
                                                        address['Address']
                                                                [index]
                                                            ['Latitude']),
                                                    double.parse(
                                                        address['Address']
                                                                [index]
                                                            ['Longitude'])),
                                                zoom: 16.0,
                                                tilt: 50),
                                        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                                        zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
                                        compassEnabled: false,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                        showAddress
                                            ? address['Address'][index]
                                                ['NickName']
                                            : '...',
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .subtitle1),
                                    SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Get.to(EditAddressPage(
                                                address: address['Address']
                                                    [index]));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // showDeleteConfirmation(context);
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

I have a simple small map in a container and I am creating a marker inside onMapCreated but don't know what it's not showing on the map. All thing is working fine just this marker not showing.

I also use setState etc but not working

Answer (score 0):

#### You forgot to add your `markers` to `GoogleMap` widget

```
GoogleMap(
....
markers: _markers,
...
```